# To log on to this remote computer, you must be granted the allow log on through terminal services

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-terminal-services

I am pretty sure that I have given a particular user to access a server, by adding her to RDP group of that server. But she can't access whereas other members of her team can access that machine. How it is possible when all are given the same kind of permission?

Comment: `1.` Check the Local Security Policy and make sure that the groups you expect have indeed been granted the `Allow logon through Terminal Services` user right. `2.` Double check the membership of those groups. `3.` Check the Security tab of the RDP-Tcp connection in Terminal Services manager and verify that the aforementioned groups have the `User Access` and Guest Access` permissions set to `Allow`.